# How to pass prev_node argument as a Node instance in Linked List insertion method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I implemented a method to insert an element after a specified node in a Linked List:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # Inserting a new node at the beginning
    def push_node(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    # Inserting a new node after the given node
    def insert_node_after(self, data, prev_node):
        if self.head is None: self.push_node(data
        # if prev_node is None: self.push_node(data)
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def print_list(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node is not None:
            print(f'{current_node.data} -> ', end='')
            current_node = current_node.next
        print(f'None')
```

I have this driver code, but it gives an error:

```
llist = LinkedList()
llist.push_node(4)
llist.push_node(3)
llist.push_node(2)
llist.push_node(1)
llist.push_node(100)

llist.insert_node_after(5, 2)
```

The `llist.insert_node_after(5, 2)` call leads to this error:

> `new_node.next = prev_node.next`
> Attribute error: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

How can I pass the `prev_node` argument as a `Node` instance to the `insert_node_after` method?

Answer (score 0):

`prev_node` cannot be the *value* of a node, but must be a node reference.

There are several ways to solve this. One is to create a method `find_node` that will return the first node in the list that has the given value. Then you can pass that returned node reference as `prev_node`.

Like this:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def find_node(self, data):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            if node.data == data:
                return node
            node = node.next

    # ...rest of your methods
```

Then in your main program:

```
llist.insert_node_after(5, llist.find_node(2))
```